# jquery generates new hashes only with integers and not with strings

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, hash

I am working with hashes with AJAX, jquery and php to return values dynamically based on select options. I had this working when running with id's but now that I am using column names it has stopped working. Something has broken when going from integers to strings and I cant work out what has exactly happened.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '?ajax_step=1',
        type: "POST",
        data: frm.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == 1) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    var frmGroup = frm.find('.frg-box'+i);
                    if (data.hash[i] !== frmGroup.find('input').val()) {
                        frmGroup.find('select').html(data.box[i]?data.box[i]:'');
                        frmGroup.find('input').val(data.hash[i]);
                        show_hide_select(frmGroup.find('select'));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert(data.status);
            }
        }
    });
```

Above is the AJAX I am using to post off. I am almost positive this is causing the issue.

Below is the PHP Im using to make the hashes. Although I do not belive this is an issue it still could be helpful.

```
$box1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['box1']);
$box2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['box2']);
```

Here I getting returns from functions

```
$ajax['box'][1] = function1();
$ajax['box'][2] = function2();
```

This is where I would generate the hashes to give back to the form on AJAX success

```
$ajax['hash'][1] = md5($ajax['box'][1]);
$ajax['hash'][2] = md5($ajax['box'][2]);
```

Below is the HTML for the selects and the hashes

```
<?php
$field_name = 'box1';?>
  <div class="form-group frg-<?php echo $field_name; ?> <?php echo $_ERROR[$field_name] ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
  <select class="form-control box1" name="<?php echo $field_name; ?>" id="<?php echo $field_name; ?>"></select>
  <?php echo $_ERROR[$field_name] ? '<span class="help-block">' . $_ERROR[$field_name] . '</span>' : ''; ?>
  <input name="box1hash" class="box1hash" type="hidden"<?php echo ($_POST['box1hash'] ? $_POST['box1hash'] : ''); ?> />
  </div>
<?php
$field_name = 'box2';?>
  <div class="form-group frg-<?php echo $field_name; ?> <?php echo $_ERROR[$field_name] ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
  <select class="form-control box2" name="<?php echo $field_name; ?>" id="<?php echo $field_name; ?>"></select>
  <?php echo $_ERROR[$field_name] ? '<span class="help-block">' . $_ERROR[$field_name] . '</span>' : ''; ?>
  <input name="box2hash" class="box2hash" type="hidden"<?php echo ($_POST['box2hash'] ? $_POST['box2hash'] : ''); ?> />
  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: New hashes are not being generated now that the values are strings

Comment: And how does that manifest? Is there any error? From where exactly in your code onwards do things go wrong? It might help to post the complete  relevant code, including HTML.

Comment: There is no error. It's just that nothing happens. The way it should work is that when the js detects that a hash has changed it will val the hash and return a new select based on the value. I would add the whole file but it is pretty large so I will trim it down to just the two hashes sections mentioned. I am struggling to detect where the problem actually is. As far as my eye can see there shouldn't be a problem with it since md5() is not specific to integers